# Factorization of prime number products

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization

I've making some research about RSA, and see that it is working with products of two prime numbers and difficulty of factorization... But why we can't make assumptions of primes like this way...

Here is a example, 27221 is product of two three digit primes, so we can think last digits of primes can be

ab1

cd1

or

ab9

cd9

or

ab3

cd7

or

ab7

cd3

So it seems to me thinking like this and going backwards for every digit of products with computer power could work. What is problem of my logic?

Comment: Well, if the primes involved are small then this kind of search will work just fine.  But for cryptography the primes might have $100$ digits and then the search simply takes too long.

Comment: Yes I know it will take long, but it seems it won't take longer than normal factorization way.

Comment: Ok, but it's no use if it takes years to do the calculation.

Comment: Efficient algorithms such as *Pollard's rho algorithm* and *Fermat's prime factorization algorithm* lead to vastly superior speedups compared to the simple constraint described by the OP—especially in the general case.

Comment: I flagged my question with similar one. Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just example:
$$p\times q = 6460651 \times 3765833  = 24329732737283.$$

$\bmod 10$: last digit '$3$': there are $4$ pairs of candidates ($2$ ordered ones): 
$$\_\_1\times\_\_3,\\ \_\_3\times\_\_1,\\ \_\_7\times\_\_9,\\ \_\_9\times\_\_7.$$

$\bmod 100$: last digits '$83$': there are $40$ pairs of candidates ($20$ ordered ones): 
$$\_\_01\times\_\_83,\\ \_\_11\times\_\_53,\\ \_\_21\times\_\_23,\\ \_\_31\times\_\_93,\\ \cdots \\  \_\_79\times\_\_77, \\  \_\_89\times\_\_47, \\ \_\_99\times\_\_17.$$

$\bmod 1000$: last digits '$283$': there are $400$ pairs of candidates.

$\bmod 10000$: last digits '$7283$': there are $4000$ pairs of candidates.

$\;\;\cdots$

$\;\;\cdots$

Complexity grows exponentially.

Number of candidates is comparable with value described by 'last digits'. Finally, number of candidates is comparable with the whole product.

Of course, we can stop this process considering exactly one half of last digits (digits '$2737283$' of this example). But it cannot help essentially: number $\sqrt{p\times q}$ is huge too in practice.

Answer (score 3):

you can't reduced it other than that since a necessary condition for primes is that they end with $1,3,7,9$ but there is no condition about second digit or third or fourth and so on..., so this is the limit of this approach.

Comment: for each digit we can make assumption like we made for previous (next digit I mean) and connect each possibility to previous ones... Isn't that work? Can't we calculate this way. I know it will take time about possibilities but it isn't infinite...

Comment: But from the second digit on, its the same as trial division factoring, since the possibilities for the second digit and on are $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ so back to square one.